# Converting a Rails project to use Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am following the official guide on how to set up Docker Compose with a Rails/PostgreSQL app here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

I have created the required files in my project root.

This part of the instructions is unclear to me:

> Next, create a bootstrap Gemfile which just loads Rails. It’ll be
> overwritten in a moment by rails new.
>
> `ruby source 'https://rubygems.org' gem 'rails', '~>5'`
>
> Create an empty Gemfile.lock to build our Dockerfile.
>
> `touch Gemfile.lock`

I have an existing rails project I am trying to Dockerise, so I already have a Gemfile. Do I create a second Gemfile, and if so, where?

What is the significance of a 'bootstrap Gemfile'? Isn't every Gemfile a boostrap Gemfile?

Comment: Can you add yr dockerfile ? I wanna see, what exactly you have added and wants to done...